# Movie ("The Host"?) with alien taking over human bodies and "solving" the problems of human society

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

A few years ago (or, maybe, more than a few) I saw a movie on Netflix. I thought that it was called "The Host," but when I went to find this movie again I found two other movies that are clearly different (one was made in 2020, and thus is too new, and the other is about a monster in Korea, which is very different).

The movie takes place after a mostly successful alien invasion in which the aliens take over human bodies and live as humans in a modified version of human society. The opening scene of the movie has a voice-over that talks about how the problems of humanity (war, poverty, etc.) have been eliminated, and introduces the fact that the aliens have taken over. The aliens have a pure CGI appearance, and spend many years traveling between planets.

Comment: Is this based on Damon Knight's "Sea Venture" trilogy? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CV_(novel))

Comment: @LSemi The two existing answers are almost certainly correct, but I can't say where the creators of that movie got their inspiration from.

Comment: Presumably, from the Stephenie Meyer book it's an adaptation of

Comment: @john01dav It is 100% The Stephenie Meyer book by the same name. My (then) girlfriend read this book while we were in highschool and she was coming from her Twilight obsession. We also saw the movie together. The [Wikipedia article confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(2013_film)#cite_ref-boxofficemojo_2-2:~:text=adapted%20from%20Stephenie%20Meyer's%202008%20novel%20of%20the%20same%20name.).

Comment: If I type "the host" or "the host movie" into Google, or [into Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host), I get the 2013 version you're looking for on the first page, and [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(2006_film)) for the 2006 Korean movie also links to the 2013 one ("Not to be confused with The Host (2013 film)").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a 2013 *The Host* movie which matches that description.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(2013_film)):

> **The human race has been taken over by small parasitic aliens called "Souls". They travel to planets inserting themselves into a host body of that planet's dominant species** while suppressing the host's consciousness. **Deeming the humans too violent to deserve the planet, they have now almost successfully taken over Earth.** The consciousness of the original owner is erased, but the Souls can access the host's memories, and occupied hosts are identifiable by silver rings in the hosts' eyes.

From the opening scene:

> The Earth is at peace. There is no hunger. There is no violence. The environment is healed. Honesty, courtesy and kindness are practiced by all. Our world has never been more... perfect. Only, it is no longer our world. We've been invaded by an alien race. They occupy the bodies of almost all human beings on the planet. The few humans who have survived are on the run.

Answer (score 4):

This is presumably the 2013 film [*The Host*](https://imdb.com/title/tt1517260/). It matches pretty well.

> The human race has been taken over by small parasitic aliens called "Souls". They travel to planets inserting themselves into a host body of that planet's dominant species while suppressing the host's consciousness. Deeming the humans too violent to deserve the planet, they have now almost successfully taken over Earth. The consciousness of the original owner is erased, but the Souls can access the host's memories, and occupied hosts are identifiable by silver rings in the hosts' eyes.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *The Host* (2013)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(2013_film))</sub>

You can see the trailer below:

Comment: I'm amused that the two trailer images posted in these answers are pretty much identical, but mirrored for some reason.  I wonder which is the original?